# Uploaded binary did not appear on iTunes connect under build section

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode 8.1 and Objective-C code. I uploaded my two applications through archives using Organiser. Organiser says application uploaded successfully but it is doesn't appear in iTunes Connect. I can't understand. I uploaded my binary on 15/12/2016 time 8:35 till now I don't see it on iTunes Connect.

I made some r&d also on the same topic. Some say to wait for some time, but this time it look too long.

I am not able to submit the binary for review. 
Please help if any one face such kind of issue.

I published several applications but this is the first time I faced this issue.

Comment: Still did not appear on the iTunes store any help is great.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, some times ago, and my solution is call the contact of `apple`, there is a link for `phone` numbers:https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

After my call, the servicer will give you a `case-number`, you save it, and after some time (such as: one hour, less or more), you call back, and give the `case-number`, the server will tell you your `binary` where is the mistoken.

My mistoken is adapte `iOS 10`, in the `info.plist` did not add the permission info (which is new to `iOS10`), so I must add it and export `.ipa` again.